# Ifinite Scroll View for games in android studio

Tags: android, infinite-scroll

i want to do a game in android studio but my problem is that i dont know how to do a scroll view. I search in the internet but i dont understand or it doesnt work for me. Someone can help me? i am very new in programing

Answer (score 0):

You only must do the next code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="1">

        <!-- What do you want Buttons, text, etc... -->

    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <!-- What do you want Buttons, text, etc... -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Is an example I hope example help you.